# How to pass GET params to simpleform input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have the following `link_to` and want to use it's params in the form on the page that it directs to. Not sure how to do it...

Here's the link on a template:

```
<%= link_to 'Create Account', shop_account_signup_from_checkout_path(:order_id => @order.id) %>
```

The link redirects to another template with this form on:

```
<%= simple_form_for @web_user, shop_account_signup_from_checkout_path, id: 'signupForm' do |f| %>

  <%= f.input #I want the :order_id from the get request to be passed in here# %>

<% end %>
```

How do i pass in the value of `:order_id`?

Cheers

Comment: where are you calling the template? show us that whole page

Answer (score 2):

Your views have access to the `params` hash that was passed into the action they're being rendered from, so the simplest way for what you've shown here is just to change that method call in `simple_form_for` to:

```
simple_form_for @web_user, shop_account_signup_from_checkout_path(:order_id => params[:order_id]) #, ...etc.
```